# Use of search and join functions in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search

EDIT:
I have listened to your ideas and decided to use HashMaps instead of ArrayLists, which proven to be much quicker, when performing a search. Unfortunately I got stuck on implementing the Join function, as it doesn't join data from two different text files. Instead it only outputs an index number of the data I am looking for. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have a few text files, which contain around 200,000 entries of data.

The files are as follows:
- artists.txt (contains song id and artist name)
- albums.txt (contains song id, song title, production year, artist id, producer id, cost)
- production.txt (contains song id, artist id, number of artists involved)
- studio.txt (contains studio location and producer id)

I need to implement an algorithm, which will scan through the document to find specified data in the shortest amount of time.

I will give you an example: I want to find the name of the artist (from artists.txt), who produced the song titled (from albums.txt) in a particular year. I also want to join these two tables, so the output will show the selected data from both files.

The current implementation takes a very long time to find a specified entry (40 seconds to display all the artists names starting with an A), because it scans through the whole document. I have been told my code should be able to sort this out in fractions of seconds. I was thinking about adding HashMaps/TreeMaps instead of the ArrayList, but I am not sure if this will change anything.

Could you please recommend a better way of implementing this? I am wondering what data types should I use and what would be the quickest and most suitable algorithm to deal with this problem.

I need to say I am very new to JAVA and therefore I don't know much on this topic, but I am eager to try your recommendations.

I am not looking for a ready solution, I just want to know your opinion on this topic and hopefully get some hints on how to get the desired effect.

Edited code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class Table {
    String line;
    int columns;
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> grid;

    public Table(int columns)
    {
        grid = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public Table(int columns, String filename) throws Exception
    {
        grid = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        this.columns = columns;

        BufferedReader fh =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));


        int lineNum = 0;

        //Add all the lines from text file
        while(null != (line=fh.readLine()))
        {
            String[] parts = line.split("\t");
            //Separate the text file into parts
            String name = parts[0];
            String id = parts[1];
            //Create new ids
            if(!grid.containsKey(id))
                grid.put(id,new ArrayList<String>());

            //Add a name to each id
            grid.get(id).add(name);
        }
    }

    public class comp implements Comparator<ArrayList<String>> { 
        int whichCol;

        public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) { 
            return o1.get(whichCol).compareTo(o2.get(whichCol));
        } 
    }

    public Table SelectAll(int colNum, String val)
    {
        Table result = new Table(this.columns);
        for(ArrayList<String> row:this.grid.values())
        {
            if (row.size()<=colNum)
                System.out.println("Error: "+row.toString());
            if (!row.get(colNum).startsWith(val))
            {
                result.grid.put(row.get(colNum), row);
                System.out.println(row);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Table Join(int col1, Table r, int col2)
    {
        Table result = new Table(this.columns+r.columns);
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> sorrid = (HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>) this.grid.clone();
        comp mycomp = new comp();
        mycomp.whichCol = col1;

        //For everyone in the first one, check everyone in second one
        for(ArrayList<String> i: this.grid.values())
        {
            for(ArrayList<String> j: r.grid.values())
            {
                if(i.get(col1).equals(j.get(col2)))
                {
                    ArrayList<String> newrow = new ArrayList<String>();
                    newrow.addAll(i);
                    newrow.addAll(j);
                    result.grid.put(newrow.get(0), newrow); 
                }   
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void displayAll()
    {
        for(String r : grid.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(r);
            for(String n : grid.get(r))
                System.out.println(" " + n);
        }
    }

    public void displaySelected(String value)
    {
        for(String r : grid.keySet())
        {
            if(r.startsWith(value))
                System.out.println(r);
        }
    }

    public Table SelectEq(int colNum, String val)
    {
        Table result = new Table(this.columns);
        for(ArrayList<String> row:this.grid.values())
        {
            if (row.size()<=colNum)
                System.out.println("Error: "+row.toString());
            if (row.get(colNum).equals(val))
                result.grid.put(row.get(0), row);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return this.grid.size();
    }

    public Table StartsWith(int colNum, String val)
    {
        Table result = new Table(this.columns);
        for(String r : grid.keySet())
        {
            if (grid.size()<=colNum)
                System.out.println("Error: "+r.toString());
            if (r.startsWith(val))
                result.grid.put(r, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: 40sec seems like a lot. Could be that increasing buffersize of BufferReader makes a lot of diff. I'd also lose the regex, just use indexOf to search for a tab. If you insist on the regex, compile it.

Comment: Is using a database an option? Why have you tagged `mysql`?

Comment: ow and store the data in a hashtable on the key that you search on. for instance if you access artist by id, make it HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>, that way you can search with artists.get( id )

Comment: After a few changes I manage to bring up the results in 20 seconds, but it is still far away from the expected result.What do you mean by "regex"? I can't find this part anywhere in my code. So you suggest I should convert all the ArrayLists to HashMaps, is this going to make the code run faster?
@Miserable
Unfortunately not, I need to code this using only Java language. I am sorry for tagging mysql, I wasn't sure about that one. Fixed it now!

Comment: I agree with @MiserableVariable: you need a database. That's what they're meant for: storing a large amount of structured data and being hyper-fast at searching this data. Don't reinvent the wheel (especially such a complex, but freely available wheel).

Comment: @JB Nizet
I know that creating the database would be the best approach, but as I mentioned earlier I must find a solution using only Java. My task is to change the current implementation and make it run faster, when performing the search and join functions.

Comment: All databases have pure-Java JDBC drivers nowadays. And there are lots of embeddable pure-Java databases as well, some of them being in-memory databases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach/design:

- create class Artist { song, artist }
- create class Album { song, title, year, artist, producer, cost }
- create class Production { song, artist, number of artists}
- create class Studio { location, producer }

The loader instantiates these classes and add object references into several [NavigableMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html).

For example: look into albums for an artist name, specified by a year and a song title :

```
NavigableMap<Integer,Album> matchYear = albumsByYear.subMap( 2004, true, 2005, false );
NavigableMap<String,Album> matchTitle    = albumsBySongTitle.tailMap( title );
Set<Album> matchYearAndTitle = year2004.values().retainAll( titled.values());
for( Album a : matchYearAndTitle )
{
   System.out.println( a.getArtist());
}
```

and so on...

You have to define all the map, one by indexed column.